# Deploy a projet in ASP .NET Web Core 2.0 in a local network

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, publish

I want to deploy my asp net web core project in a local network. I don't really know how to make this available.

Someone has an idea how to do ?

I have tried to publish my code via Visual Studio, but an error occurred.

Build step successful but not publish step.

**Error when publish**
[image]

Logs :

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__127.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---
```

UPDATE

Publish is ok, but when I want to use the IIS management and start the website I have a website innacessible

UPDATE

On IIS Management, I have configured the project on the port 80.
When I start the server, I go to 127.0.0.1:80, my browser load something during a long time and nothing happens

Comment: Did you check the diagnostic log?

Comment: Yes but nothing very explicit

Comment: I think your publish target is wrong or inaccessible. Can you publish to a local folder and see if it works?

Comment: Yes it's work, but after the publish step, what I have to do on IIS ?

Comment: If you haven't [set up IIS you need to do that first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I have done, but not assigned the port 80 because this port is used for the DB (mysql with XAMPP)

Comment: Just try to do that not via Visual Studio.
1. Compile the binaries via Publish menu to one folder (as you already done, I guess)
2. Open IIS Management window and map your folder to the new application pool and website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I have try to use the IIS Management window but I start the website, I have an error this site is inaccessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was when I publish my project from Visual Studio 2017 to select "Self-container" in deployment mode.

In the IIS, I have selected the folder "publish"